# Spring boot read map from .properities file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have `.properties` file witch are values for a map of type

```
AF:Afghanistan
AL:Albania
DZ:Algeria
AS:American Samoa
AD:Andorra
AO:Angola
AI:Anguilla
```

the `properties` file has a name `countries.properties` so its not the `application.properties` one i have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work.The java code is this

```
    @Value("#{${}}")
    private Map<String, String> countryOptions;
```

The annotaion is intenionaly left blank.
How can i make it load from the `countries.properties`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution using `@PropertySource("classpath:countryOptions.properties")`

`@Value("#{${countryOptions}}")`

and at `countryOptions.properties` i changed the map to `countryOptions={"US":"United States",....}

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a version prior to SpringBoot 2.4.0, Spring Boot allows including additional configuration files using the `spring.config.location` and `spring.config.additional-location` properties defined in `application.properties` file.

After Spring Boot 2.4.0, a new property called `spring.config.import` has been introduced which supports multiple features:

- Adding several files or directories
- Files can be loaded either from the classpath or from an external directory
- Indicating if the startup process should fail if a file is not found, or if it's an optional file
- Importing extensionless files

Example:

```
# Case 1
spring.config.import=classpath:additional-application.properties
# Case 2
spring.config.import=classpath:additional-application[.yml]
# Case 3
spring.config.import=optional:file:./external.properties
# Case 4
spring.config.import=classpath:additional-application-properties
```

Comment: So i tried `spring.config.import=classpath:countries.properties` in `application.properties` and 
 `@Value("#{${spring.config.import}}") `  at the controller but still dont work.